# ./src/components/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './{Component}' in '/src/components'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

After I change all file from `jsx` to `tsx`, I get this error:

> ./src/components/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './Header'
>   in '/Users/khuongpham/WebFrontEnd/home/src/components'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do correct [Webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions), add `.tsx` under `resolve` property:

```
....

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
}
....
```

FYI: It seems if you want to integrate [TypeScript into React](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html), you still need to install some libraries and development dependencies to let Webpack and React play well.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed all files from `jsx` to `tsx` then what is the reason for leaving `index.js`? 
Why don't you change it to `index.tsx` or at least `index.ts`?

As far as I'm concerned, `ts` and `js` can't directly interact with each other.

If you are writting a `ts` or `tsx` file and you want to import a `js` file (or `js` library) you will need something called `type declaration` file which, most of the time, can be found here: https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

In your case, you are trying to import `typescript` from `javascript` and that is probably the problem. *Changing **`index.js`** to **`index.ts`** may help*.

Comment: I tried changing from `index.js` to `index.ts` but it says error: `./src/components/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/khuongpham/WebFrontEnd/home/src/components/index.js'`

Comment: Did you update the `entry` section in `webpack` configuration file? https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Comment: And if you are using `webpack` watcher, try stopping and re-running it.

Comment: "As far as I'm concerned, ts and js can't directly interact with each other." 

I have a test project with index.jsx and a component.tsx which is used by index.jsx and it works fine.